# Limpieza DataFrame Phyton

Tags: python, dataframe, datos

Tengo este Dataframe con varias columnas y registros y tengo el problema que se ve. Se puede ver que los registros salen acompañados de otros caracteres que no necesito para nada y no se muy bien como resolver este problema.

Estoy iniciándome en Python por temas de trabajo y yo siempre había hecho mis cosillas en R. He intentando probar con cosas como gsub o substring que se utilizan en R para extraer subcadenas y luego ya limpiar el texto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Puedes agregar el `dataframe` como texto?

Comment: Esos caracteres son tabulados y saltos de linea, puedes quitarlos antes de ingresarlo al DataFrame. Te daría una respuesta, pero no quiero hacerte la tarea. Podrías agregar lo que has intentado hasta ahora para "limpiar" el DataFrame por favor? Asi demostrarás que eres parte del esfuerzo por responder tu propia duda, tu pregunta será mejor recibida y no parecerá que pides que te hagan la tarea.

Comment: Buenas, perdón si pareció que simplemente quería que me pasaran el problema resuelto sin más. Estoy empezando con Python por temas de trabajo y siempre había hecho mis cosillas en R. Tampoco sabía que eran caracteres tabulados o saltos de línea. Por eso, lo que estuve mirando fue temas de crear subcadenas e ir limpiando el texto, por ahí iban mis tiros. Estuve buscando cosas parecidas a un gsub o substring en R pero no encontré nada tampoco.

Comment: No hay problema, pero recuerda editar la pregunta c: Estuve leyendo la documentación de esas funciones. Sus equivalentes en Python parecen ser (no soy experto) [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#re.sub) del modulo re y una sintaxis especial llamada [slicing](https://www.oreilly.com/content/how-do-i-use-the-slice-notation-in-python/) respectivamente. Igual ninguna de las dos te las recomiendo para "limpiar" el texto. Te recomiendo usar el método [strip](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) de las cadenas.